Tsconfig-paths cannot find package
I have a project like this where I import a lib from another dir outside of the current one
.
|
-  systems_programming_lib
  -  tsconfig.json
  -  package.json
  -  src
  -  bin
|
|
-  data_storage
  -  tsconfig.json
  -  package.json
  -  src
  -  bin

Where data storage refrences code from the systems_programming_lib
data_storage/tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "bin",
    "lib": [
      "ESNext",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "strict": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "disableSizeLimit": true,
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "paths": {
      "@sys_lib/*": [
        "../systems_programming_lib/bin/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../systems_programming_lib"
    }
  ]
}

and for vscode and typescript it works fine

and compiling works fine
but when running with node I get the following error
node -r tsconfig-paths/register bin/index.js:
node:internal/process/esm_loader:34
      internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                                ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@sys_lib/models' imported from /home/ledrake/files/systems_programming/data_storage/bin/messaging/Consumer.js
Did you mean to import /home/ledrake/files/systems_programming/systems_programming_lib/bin/models/event.js?
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:853:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:910:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1130:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:396:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:365:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:240:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v20.11.1

